# Форматирование результата ответа mysql

Tags: mysql

есть таблица

```
id | name    | surname    | patronymic 

1  | Иван    | Черненко    | Викторович
2  | Николай | Пертров     | Александрович
```

Как с помощью Mysql запроса получить таблицу вида

```
id | fullname
1  | Черненко И.В.
2  | Петров Н.А.
```

обратите внимание что точки в инициалах тоже надо подставить.

Помогите пожалуйста, есть ли подходящие функции в mysql?

Благодарю!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT /* ... , */
    CONCAT(surname, 
           ' ', 
           LEFT(name,1), 
           '. ', 
           LEFT(patronymic,1), 
           '.'
    ) fullname
/* ... */
```

Comment: Спасибо большое именно это и искал

Comment: @Dmitriy, если ответ вас устраивает как решение, то слева от него жмите галку.